# Upgrade and migration of PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.4 to PostgreSQL 16

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a really old PostgreSQL and PostGIS bundle (10 and 2.4), that I want to upgrade and migrate to a different server. Upgrading postgres alone wouldn't be a problem, but PostGIS makes it tricky. I've come across this [PostGIS support matrix](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS) and it looks like I'm going to have to this like this:

1. Upgrade PostGIS to 2.5 in existing installation
2. Dumpall and migrate to a different server with Postgresql 12 and PostGIS 2.5
3. Upgrade PostGIS to 3.4 on database level
4. Upgrade to Postgresql 16 with PostGIS 3.4

Is this the right way to do it? Are there any caveats that I should be aware of?

Comment: If required downtime for pg_dumpall + restore on the new server is acceptable, then make a dump on pg10/postgis2.5 and restore it on pg16/postgis3.4 directly. Difficulties are needed if the database needs to be upgraded via pg_upgrade.

Comment: Your plan looks alright to me.